# How to send data from multiples tables (db.sqlite) to php

Tags: android

With this code I send information from my local sqlite database to my server(mysql) and it works fine. But I only send data from the table1. If I want to send the data of all my sqlite tables to my server how I can do that?

```
public class sendInformation  {
public SQLiteDatabase newDB;
JSONObject jObject;
JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray();

public void getValues()
{
    try
    {
        newDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase("/data/data/com..../databases/...db",null,SQLiteDatabase.CONFLICT_NONE);    
    }catch(SQLException e)
    {
        Log.d("Error","Error while Opening Database");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try
    {
        Cursor c = newDB.rawQuery("Select * from table1",null);
        if (c.getCount()==0) 
        {
            c.close();
            Log.d("","no items on the table");              
        }else
        {
            c.moveToFirst();    

            while(c.moveToNext()) {
                jObject = new JSONObject();
                jObject.put("ID", c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("ID")));
                jObject.put("Notes", c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("Notes")));
                jObject.put("Cellphone", c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("Cellphone")));
                jObject.put("Date", "null");
                jObject.put("Address", "null");
                jArray.put(jObject);
            }

            c.close();
            Log.d("","ALL the data in the DB"+jArray.toString());
            int arrayLength=jArray.length();
            Log.d("","Lenght of the jArray"+arrayLength);
            HttpParams httpParams = new BasicHttpParams();
            HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParams,9000);
            HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParams, 9000);

            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParams);

            String url = "http://ipaddress/..../test.php?arrayLength="+arrayLength;

            HttpPost request = new HttpPost(url);
            request.setEntity(new ByteArrayEntity(jArray.toString().getBytes("UTF8")));      
            request.setHeader("json", jArray.toString());

            HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            // If the response does not enclose an entity, there is no need

            if (entity != null) {
                InputStream instream = entity.getContent();

                String result =  RestClient.convertStreamToString(instream);
                Log.i("Read from server", result); 
            }
        }       
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException uee) {
        Log.d("Exceptions", "UnsupportedEncodingException");
        uee.printStackTrace();
    }catch (Throwable t) {
        Log.d("","request fail"+t.toString());
    }

    this.newDB.close(); 
  }
}
```

As you can see, I get all the data from `table1` and I create a jsonObject.

- I pass that to the test.php file, but if I make another query from table2,table3..., I have to put the values of the second and third table in the same JsonObject?
- If I do that, how will I know which data is from which table?
- If I can send multiples jsonobject, how do I do that and how will I receive that data in my test.php file.

Right now I do it with `$json = file_get_contents('php://input');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already have half the solution. Just replicate the code that creates and populates a JsonObject for each additional table, and add those to your JsonArray. Instead of a JsonArray you can use another JsonObject - it can contain other JsonObjects.

On the server, just use json_decode($json, true) and you will get your data as an array of arrays - dump the result to a file with print_r() so you can see the structure of the data.

Comment: how i can add a JSONobject in to another JSONobject?

Comment: i only make the same for all the tables and send all the information in the jArray after each table i put jArray.put("//") so i cand separate the data form the diferent tables